# Cохранить фаил в каталог с кириллическим именем

Tags: c++, qt

В общем пытаюсь сохранить фаил в каталог с русским именем , что мне надо для этого сделать ???

```
    // тут сохраненине файла, бинарника
    file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "DDR" + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".bin";
    if(file_name.isEmpty())

 // file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "результаты" + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".bin";
// а вот так вот не работает 
    if(file_name.isEmpty())
    {
        qDebug() << "хпреньа11 печенька ";
        return;
    }

    char fname[255];
    sprintf((char*)fname,"%s",file_name.toLocal8Bit().data());
    qDebug() << "fname " <<fname;

    FILE *fid=0;
    fid=fopen(fname, "wb");

    qDebug() << "K" << obm->stor->K << "NT" << obm->stor->NT;
    if(fid)
    {
        fwrite(obm->stor->RE,sizeof(double),obm->stor->K*obm->stor->NT,fid);
        fwrite(obm->stor->IM, sizeof(double),obm->stor->K*obm->stor->NT,fid);
        fclose(fid);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error save Re & Im! " << fname;
    }
    qDebug() << "END";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CTranslateUtilRun util( QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->toUnicode( "C:/Documents and Settings/результаты/Мои документы/Dir" ), "fddfdf", ETU_LUPDATE);
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: UPD: кажется, в этом проблема - Qt не любит "не"юникод в сырцах )

Comment: Не сработало  . Сложно понять  перед или после какой строчки положить этот код .

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно работаете с файлами, в Qt есть специальный класс для этого [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html), + смотрите ответ ниже)